# How to take image and video files from every folder list using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have following folder structure

```
folder1  
    1.jpg 
    1.mp4
folder2  
    2.jpg 
    2.mp4
folder3  
    3.jpg 
    3.mp4
folder4
    4.jpg 
    4.mp4
```

1. get every folder img file path and video file path
2. and put the path first li tag
3. anchor tag display video link
4. img tag src put the image link

   Touch Navigation

   For iOS and Android
  Four Skins
  With photoshop files
  Responsive layout
  Change width at any time
  Powerful API
  Public methods, callbacks

Comment: I am very happy for your folder structure. What's the question again?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP RecursiveDirectoryIterator class, docs can be found at

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php